# tcl/tk - dependency library issue in multifile starkit

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk, starkit

I am trying to create a starkit consisting of multiple tcl source files, which can be executed without problem on my machine with `wish`. However, on trying to do the same with tclkit, I got this error from one of the second level source files sourced from the toplevel one directly sourced from `main.tcl`.

```
unknown or ambiguous item type "waveform"
    while executing
"$c create waveform 0 0 -sound snd -height $v(waveh) -width $v(cWidth)  -tags [list obj wave] -debug $::debug -fill $v(wavColor) -limit $v(waveScale)"
    invoked from within
"if $v(showWave) {
    $c create waveform 0 0 -sound snd -height $v(waveh) -width $v(cWidth)  -tags [list obj wave] -debug $::debug -fill $v(wavColor) ..."
    (procedure "Redraw" line 28)
    invoked from within
"Redraw all"
    (procedure "resetDisplay" line 21)
    invoked from within
"resetDisplay"
    (file "MYAPPLICATION.vfs/TOPLEVEL.tcl" line 591)
```

`waveform` is from `snack` library, so I investigated it. The library does not have unresolved external dependency and the error would have occured much earlier if the library could not be used at all, so I have tried the following:

- Recompile `snack` library from source
- Compile `snack` directly into the tclkit runtime (rather than as a lib in vfs)
- Add `package require snack` again into the source file in question
- Make my application a package in `lib` rather than in the direct vfs directory

None of the above works. The only working way I have found is to combine all the source files into one by substituting `source`s. Therefore, I suspect this to be some kind of race condition, but I am neither able to prove it nor to debug it.

Sorry if I am missing anything important here (pretty new to tcl/tk). Would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: Which OS? I can imagine that snack only adds canvas item types if Tk is loaded before snack. When using wish, that is guaranteed. But with a tclkit that may not be the case (except on Windows).

Comment: @SchelteBron For the sake of completeness, the OS is Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, more specifically). The sequence of `require`s is indeed the reason that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snack is primarily a sound toolkit. It adds a `snack::sound` command to Tcl for working with audio (playback, recording, etc.). When used in combination with Tk, it also adds a waveform item type to the Tk canvas. For this to work, Tk has to be loaded before snack. When using `wish`, Tk is loaded from the start. But with a tclkit (unless running on windows), Tk has to be loaded with a `package require Tk` command.

I can reproduce your error using the following code:

```
package require snack
package require Tk

snack::sound snd
snd read foo.wav

canvas .c
.c create waveform 0 0 -sound snd
```

The error goes away when I swap the first two lines around. So:

```
package require Tk
package require snack
```

Comment: It solves the problem. It was really silly of me not being able to identify the problem XwX

Thank you so much for your kind guidance! I have marked the answer as accepted and will cast the upvote once I earn enough reputation points. (Sorry for that, I am still very new here (^_^;) )